# How to find adjacent elements in multidimensional list in Python?

Tags: python

Here I have a multidimensional list in python.
Suppose I take an input, how do I find the number of adjacent elements of that input which are alphabets other than itself? If there are multiple indices at which the element is placed, then we have to print the maximum of all possibility.
For example, the number of adjacent elements which are equal to 'R' is 2.

```
z=input()
#suppose c='R'
#print the number of equal and adjacent elements, for c='R' it is 2
l=[['G', '.', 'B', 'C'], ['A', '.', 'R', 'Z'], ['.', '.', 'R', 'B']]



#G.BC
#A.RZ
#..RB
```

This is how I tried it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
x,y,z=input().split()
l=[]
c=[]
x,y=int(x),int(y)

def f(e):
    ls=[]
    a=e[0]
    b=e[1]
    for i in range(int(x)):
        for j in range(int(y)):
            t=l[i][j]
            if i==a and t!=z and t!='.':
                if j==b-1 or j==b+1:
                    ls.append(t)
            if j==b and t!=z and t!='.':
                if i==a-1 or i==a+1:
                    ls.append(t)
    ls=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(ls))
    
    return ls
                

for i in range (0,int(x)):
    s=""
    s=input()
    sl=list(s)
    for j in range(int(y)):
        if z==sl[j]:
            c.append([i,j])
    l.append(sl)
d=0
for i in range(len(c)):
    m=f(c[i])
    d=max(d,len(m))
print(d)
```

Here function f is used to create a list of elements which satisfy the conditions.
z is the character which the user inputs and x,y is the dimension of the list.

```
   'OO
    WW
    WW'
    #Here if the input is W, then the answer should be one.
    
   'G.B.
    .RR.
    TTT.'
    #Here if input is R, then the answer is 2
```

Comment: Can you provide extra examples of expected input and output?

Comment: Your current wording is unclear. You ask how to find the number of adjacent elements, but then show an implementation. Is this implementation working?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are looking for the count of unique letters that are not equal to your target letter, after making a list of all neighbors of all instances of that target letter?

Comment: @Flater Yes, and also it should not be equal to '.'

Comment: What is this code actually supposed to be doing? Is there a problem that this solves? I think that might help clear up what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To be honest, I can't quite confirm what you actually want. Since you ask in `Code Review`, I assume you want someone to review your code and give some advice.

#### advice

1. Please always use meaningful name to variable and function name, don't use something like `a`, `b`, `x`, `y`, `f`. They are confusing to the people who read your code. When you read the code and following advice, you will find it. It is OK use `i`, `j` in some simple loop. So I replaced most of them, some of them may be not so proper.
2. There is no need to record the adjacent elements in `ls`(result), just `+1` to the result of `f`(find_adjacent_elements).
3. There is also no need to check the whole `l`(map), just check the `z`(base_char) up\down\left\right 4 direction. It can speed up your code especially the size of map is huge.
4. Please read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it can make your code more readable. Such as `a=e[0]` should be `a = e[0]`.
5. I fix some other small issues, please check the difference between my code and your code.

#### fixed code:

```
def find_adjacent_elements(base_pos):
    result = 0
    directions = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]]
    for direction in directions:
        try:
            adjacent_element = map[base_pos[0] + direction[0]][base_pos[1] + direction[1]]
            if adjacent_element != base_char and adjacent_element != ".":
                result += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return result
                
print("please input the columns,rows and base character")
columns,rows,base_char = input().split()
map = []
base_char_pos = []
columns,rows = int(columns),int(rows)
for i in range(columns):
    map_line = list(input())
    for j in range(rows):
        if base_char == map_line[j]:
            base_char_pos.append([i,j])
    map.append(map_line)
ans = 0
for i in range(len(base_char_pos)):
    ans = max(ans,find_adjacent_elements(base_char_pos[i]))
print(ans)
```

#### test:

```
please input the columns,rows and base character
4 4 R
..A.
.BRC
.DRE
..F.

3

please input the columns,rows and base character
2 2 R
R.
.R

0

please input the columns,rows and base character
3 2 W
OO
WW
WW

1

please input the columns,rows and base character
3 4 R
G.B.
.RR.
TTT.

2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I will keep those points in mind . I understood how you just checked the positions around the base character made it more efficient. Thanks for taking out your time and helping me!